# Container for image is not flexible when parent change size

Tags: html, image, css, containers

I'll start from the beginning. I create a responsive website, where I have an element which change height. In it is located a picture, to which I had to create a container to be able to position the new elements in relation to it. Unfortunately, after resizing (e.g. when you turn the phone) - the container does not change the width along with the image. If you refresh the value of a parameter (e.g. the "inspect element" remove and add "display"), it is already correctly set. How to solve this problem?

```js
var i = 0;
$('button').on('click', function() {
  if (i%2) $('.background').css('height', '200px');
  else $('.background').css('height', '300px');i++;
});
```

```css
.background {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.background > .container {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}

.background > .container > img {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bVzpweTJvhc/hqdefault.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<button>Change</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `container` is displayed as `inline` it works (and I don't know why ... yet)

```js
var i = 0;
$('button').on('click', function() {
  if (i%2) $('.background').css('height', '200px');
  else $('.background').css('height', '300px');i++;
});
```

```css
.background {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.background > .container {
  display: inline;
}

.background > .container > img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bVzpweTJvhc/hqdefault.jpg">
  </div>
  <span>I move too....</span>
</div>
<br><br>
<button>Change</button>
```

Comment: I thought that it is it, but unfortunately no. If you add "background-color: white" to the container, then you can see that image width is different than container, so I still do not have any reference to right edge of image :(

Comment: @Invictus Updated my answer

Comment: It's not a perfect solution, but solved my problem, so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
.my-container-div
{
    background-image: zoom
}
```

instead an img into a div. With this, you can play with the div and its background properties, background-size, background-position... etc.

I'd do something like this:

```
.background > .container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bVzpweTJvhc/hqdefault.jpg");
  background-size: cover;    
}
```

Comment: What is `background-image: zoom`?

Comment: Image as the background of div will not set me the dimensions, so that I could then set other elements to the image. For example I want to set other div with 20px margin from right border of image (position: absolute; right 20px).

Answer (score 0):

Your `container` class and image don't have any `width` defined for them. That is the reason. Give your `container` a `width:50%` and the for the image `width:100%`

Comment: Did you try this? ... It doesn't work other than distort the image

Comment: It is not defined width, because it is set automatically to save proportions of image and do not distort it like said @LGSon. Height is defined as you can see.

Comment: When the dome DOM gets updated nothing happens to the container div because its state remains unchanged. The image’s size changes due to its height attribute and since there is no width attribute, it will overflow the container. You could make the image stay inside container, by using `overflow:hidden` but with pure CSS, I can’t think of a to make the container, the size of the image.

Comment: Well, why post a CSS answer if _with pure CSS, I can’t think of a to make the container, the size of the image_?